# How to deploy a laravel project?

Tags: configuration, laravel-4

Like the question says How I should deploy a laravel project? that is already on github.

Do I need to install laravel whit the composer on the web server or just copy the whole directory of my proyect that have the folders app,public,vendor and the other files?

Comment: Do the `git clone <git_repository>` and if vendor packages are not checked into the `<git_repository>` do the `composer install` once the repository successfully cloned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on your server. If you hava full access to server (such as vps or even dedicated), it's good to install composer there and do laravel installation use `Composer`, allow you to easily manage your project later. Otherwise, yes, you have to copy all files including `vendor` directory to your server.

Note, if you're going to deploying to shared server which you have no full access to, you probably want to create fresh laravel installation (production version of your project) with `--prefer-dist` and `--no-dev` locally first. It'll reduce application file size.